# How can I install Seamonkey on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, lts, browser, seamonkey

I got a tar.bz2 file but the help I found didn't help so I thought I'd ask here.

I downloaded the linux 32-bit file on their main [site](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/). My system is 64-bit.

The link on that site downloaded these files:

[image: downloaded files]

Comment: You really need to provide more information. Where did you get this file from? Post the link. Is it for 32-bit or 64-bit Seamonkey? The "official" download is the 32-bit one. Is your system 32-bit or 64-bit? What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: So is your system 32-bit or 64-bit? Please edit your question to provide the full output of `uname -a`.

Comment: Why is there a `.part` file? This most likely indicates the download didn't finish correctly.

Comment: Your right but I'm stuck again and I've even tried Adam and Candra's [suggestions](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-a-tar.bz2-file-in-Ubuntu). The first command just says it doesn't exist. @pomsky

Comment: @CloudE11 Did you `cd` to the correct directory first before running those commands? For example if you have downloaded the `tar.bz2` file to your Downloads folder, then you need to run `cd ~/Downloads` before those commands.

Comment: @pomsky Can you post them as I should enter them in terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can recommend to install SeaMonkey browser using [UbuntuZilla APT repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/). This package will be updated on every apt upgrade.

You need to execute the following commands to add repository, its key and package installation:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 2667CA5C
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install seamonkey-mozilla-build
```

You will get SeaMonkey 2.53.2 with this method.

Comment: The terminal just loads for ages with the first command, I waited a couple minutes.

Comment: The first command consists of 3 lines - after the first line, the terminal will appear to "hang" until it gets the final `EOF`

Comment: Great, that installed it. Basically you've 4 commands in that box. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The version of The Mozilla browser that I have just installed on my Debian based Zorin computer is called `seamonkey-mozilla-build`

"This tutorial will be showing you how to install `SeaMonkey` on Ubuntu 16.04. SeaMonkey, formerly known as Mozilla Suite, is an open-source, community-driven Internet application suite. The latest stable release is SeaMonkey 2.46 at the time of this writing."
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/how-to-install-seamonkey-on-ubuntu-16-04

Following the instructions here, I ended up with a working version of `SeaMonkey 2.53.1` that gets installed with `apt` and is launched properly from the main menu system.

The steps are;

Add the repository to your sources list.
repository

```
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main
```

Sources List

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Get the GPG key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 2667CA5C
```

do an update.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install the program.

```
sudo apt-get install seamonkey-mozilla-build
```

Okay so here is all the `seamonkey` .deb archive files at sourceforge.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/s/seamonkey-mozilla-build/

Hope this helps.