# Unable to read source lists in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

In my previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081382/how-can-i-install-seamonkey-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) I got an answer N0bert and I believe it caused the problem apparent in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQdAE.png) and post title.

"malformed line 2 in source list"

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Regards

Comment: What does your `sources.list` say?

Comment: Anyway, my line is correct if you copied it exactly as shown in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081422/66509). Please add output of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The red warning dot disappeared and I can run updates and install things since I ran the [code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081382/how-can-i-install-seamonkey-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) properly, the same code that caused the problem when I input it wrong.